# Dynamic maximum width for text

Tags: width, css

So let's say I have this markup;

```
<div>
  <span>Text one</span>
  <span class="sticky">ABC</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Some other text</span>
  <span class="sticky">DEF</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Lorem dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor</span>
  <span class="sticky">GHI</span>
</div>
```

Which would - with accompanying CSS - yield a result like pictured below.

However, the problem occurs when the text in the first `span` is longer than the allotted width of the `div`. Regularly what happens is just normal text wrapping; the second `span` is bumped to the end of the second row.

However, I want this element to be just a single row. Now, of course to achieve this, you do;

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

But then what happens is the second `span` disappears into oblivion, as it's driven away by the length of the text in the first `span`.

What I'd want to achieve is what is pictured in the third example below. When the content of the first `span` is too long to be displayed, `text-overflow: ellipsis;` would cut the string with a dot-dot-dot, and the second `span` would be pushed to the very right edge (`padding` of the `div` allowing).

Essentially, the pseudo-`max-width` of the first `span` would be equal to the width of the `div`, excluding its `padding` and deducting the width of `span.sticky`, whatever that may be (as the content of it may vary, so the width is not set).

I don't know if `max-width` is actually the way to go when approaching something like this, but it's what I can use to best describe the behavior I want.

Is there a non-JS method of achieving this?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can definitely, and should be done in CSS. Apply a fixed width and fixed height on the first span. The height keeps it from stretching to multiple lines. The .sticky span then can be positioned afterwards. This can even be made fluid, using percents or ems. Something to consider, I don't know the context of the 'ABC', 'DEF', but they might better be applied using a :before or :after pseudo class if they're purely visual and not structural elements.

Here's a quick example:

```
div { 
    width: 200px; /* some amount that you set */
}
span:not(.sticky) { /* can use another selector, just wanted it to be exceptionally clear what i was referring to here */
    display: inline-block; /* so height and width actually take affect */
    max-width: 80%;
    height: 1em; /* so overflow hidden works and keeps text on one row */
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap; /* important to show ellipsis, or words will just be broken off */
}
span.sticky {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
}
```

If you want to see this working on a live site, I did this design on moolta.com. Click on 'make a challenge' and open the modal to choose a friend. The li's inside of the dropdown list are what I'm talking about. They had to become elipsis and have a button follow them, without breaking lines

Comment: I guess to make it fully dynamic, it could be improved with a small JS dohickey that calculated the actual `max-width` for the first `span` based on the width of the `div` and the actual content width of `sticky`, for the lack of similar functionality in CSS. But it's a great start.

Comment: Fiddled around to create this; http://jsfiddle.net/GEzXU/ - opinions on how smart this approach is are welcomed.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work using a dynamic width for the outer div?

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .left {
        max-width: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }

      .right {
        float: right;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="left">
      <div class="right">FOO</div>
      Lorem
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="left">
      <div class="right">FOO</div>
      Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="left">
      <div class="right">FOO</div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```